# This reopen test seems too ambiguous for a test

Tags: discussion, feature-request, disputed-review-audits

As a review test, I was asked whether this question should be reopened
on SO. The test said it had been closed as opinion-based.

[Am I using Julia right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446684)

This strikes me as a very open-ended sort of question that belongs on
programmers.sx, not the sort of specific problem question that belongs
on SO. It also seems to call for opinion, though perhaps not to the
point that every answer would be equally valid.

I suppose the system just looked at the upvotes (8), downvotes (none),
and close votes (none as far as I can tell), and after all, what else
can you do with a program? But this does not seem like the sort of
clear-cut case that should be used on a review test.

Is there a tool to easily check the statistics on this test and compare
it with other such tests? If significantly more people are saying it
should remain closed than is usual for such tests, it should probably be
removed from the test pool.

For future development, it might be a good idea to use such a
statistical tool to automatically catch tests that people are failing a
lot, temporarily suspend them from the test pool, and flag them for
review. Once reviewed, they could be marked as okay-for-tests or
not-okay-for-tests, so the tool would ignore them. (Tagging the question
feature-request for this part.)

If it's clear to others that this is a good SO question, please
enlighten me. To me it seems like the sort of open-ended question that
usually gets closed as too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: Not answering your main question, but picking up on this:
"This strikes me as a very open-ended sort of question that belongs on programmers.sx" We don't like open ended questions on Programmers either. Please don't go around suggesting that people repost their questions on sites where you have no experience of said site.

Comment: A fair criticism. Perhaps I should have said that it seems to belong there because it's more theoretical and concerned with architecture and design.

Comment: This is a question calling for discussion, as such it seems that it is not a good question for SO or Prog.SX

Comment: Hmya, every [tag] at SO has its own sensibilities.  The [julia-lang] community does things differently.  It is very small, yet has quite extra-ordinary voting and answering rates that no other language tag can touch.  I suppose you don't have to be a part of the community to review their Q+A, but it takes but a quick gander to see that the Q was much appreciated and the A specifically mentions that the topic is current within the community.  Which is why the audit failure message says "Stop, look, listen".  Never hesitate to use the Skip button.